# What is the complexity of Mixture Hidden Markov Models (MHMM)?

Tags: markov-hidden-model

I wonder what is the theoretical computational complexity of MHMM. 
Is it related to the number of alphabets in sequence mining?

Answer (score 1):

Mixture hidden markov model is not one algorithm. It's made of forward algo, viterbi algo and forward-backward algo.

The time complexity of computing the forward variable used in hidden markov models is O(N2T) In which N is the number of states and T is the length of the observations sequence.